# Error de enlazado con aplicación mínina de consola: ¿ Archivo .pro incorrecto?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake

Estoy intentando compilar una aplicación mínima para consola, usando `Qt 5.11.1`.

Mi archivo `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

class Application : public QCoreApplication {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Application( int &argc, char **argv ) : QCoreApplication( argc, argv ) { }
};

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
  Application app( argc, argv );

  return app.exec( );
}
```

Ejecuto el `qmake`, aparentemente sin errores.

> Info: creating stash file /home/Trauma/test/.qmake.stash

A continuación, intento el `make` ... y muestra el siguiente error:

> /usr/bin/ld: main.o: en la función `main`:
>   main.cpp: referencia a `vtable for Application` sin definir.
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Se que ese error se produce por algún problema con el `moc`. Mi clase hereda de `QObject`, incorpora la macro `Q_OBJECT`, y es necesario que el `moc` genere la información necesaria.

Mi archivo de proyecto `test.pro`:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
CONFIG += c++11
QT -= gui

INCLUDEPATH += include

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000

SOURCES += src/main.cpp
```

Las preguntas:

- ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade `#include "main.moc"` al final del main.cpp:

```cpp
  # ...
  return app.exec( );
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Luego ejecute *Build*->*Clean all*, *Build*->*Run qmake*, y compile devuelta.

#### TL; DR;

Qt usa el MOC(*Meta Object Compiler*) para añadir funcionalidades generadas al usar Q_OBJECT, Q_SIGNAL, Q_SLOT, Q_INVOKABLE, etc. y para ello genera otros archivos que se enlazan. En su caso Q_OBJECT se expande en el archivo "main.moc" pero no es enlazado por defecto por ello tienes que incluirlo.

Si tu clase Application estuviera declarado en un header no habría ese problema ya que qmake lo autoenlazaria.

Para mayor información lea:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html