# No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo 'archivo.moc'

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake

Estoy intentando compilar una aplicación mínima para consola, usando Qt 5.11.1. Estoy usando varios archivos en mi proyecto:

> include/application.hpp

```
#ifndef APPLICATION_HPP
#define APPLICATION_HPP

#include <QCoreApplication>

class Application : public QCoreApplication {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Application( int &argc, char **argv );
};

#endif
```

> src/application.cpp

```
#include "application.hpp"

#include <QtCore/qdebug.h>

Application::Application( int &argc, char **argv ) : QCoreApplication( argc, argv ) {
  qDebug( ) << "Application::Application( )\n";
}

#include "application.moc"
```

> src/main.cpp

```
#include "application.hpp"

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
  Application app( argc, argv );

  return app.exec( );
}
```

> test.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = backend
CONFIG += c++11
QT -= gui

INCLUDEPATH += include

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# Input
SOURCES += src/main.cpp \
           src/application.cpp
```

Ejecuto `qmake` sin problemas:

> Info: creating stash file /home/Tauma/test/.qmake.stash

Intento compilar con `make` ...

> make: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo 'application.moc', necesario para 'application.o'.  Alto.

Si elimino el `#include "application.moc"` del archivo `src/application.cpp`, vuelvo al error de [mi pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/254325/19610):

> application.cpp: referencia a 'vtable for Application' sin definir
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

- ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como señale en [mi respuesta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/254328/22539):

> Si tu clase Application estuviera declarado en un header no habría ese problema ya que qmake lo autoenlazaria.

El error es que no has incluido al .hpp al .pro. La solución en tu caso:

1. Remover el `#include application.moc` de src/application.cpp, y
2. Añadir el header al .pro:

```
HEADERS += \
    include/application.hpp
```

Comment: ¡ *Carajo* ! Tienes razón, se me olvidó añadirlo al `HEADERS`. Avergonzado me siento :'-(

Comment: @Trauma te recomiendo usar las herramientas de Qt creator para añadir o crear clases :-), asi no tendrás este tipo de problemas. Y cuando entiendas las reglas de Qt y QtCreator podras usarlo solo qmake :-)

Comment: Agradezco el consejo ... pero elegí el *nick* por algo ... ¡ *a cabezazos* se aprende mejor ! Aunque a veces me duela la cabeza ... :-)

Comment: @Trauma jajaja, solo es una recomendación de alguien quién ya se dio los cabezasos, (y aun me las doy)